# Is it possible to encrypt a message stream with the same IV each time and for it to be secure?

Tags: encryption

I know we should ideally never reuse the IV (Depending upon the mode of encryption used), but is it possible to have a protocol which uses the same IV for the message stream and is as safe as one which has a new IV every time?

Comment: There is a SIV mode that has resistance to IV re-use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an Initialization Vector (IV) required with unique data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115500/is-an-initialization-vector-iv-required-with-unique-data). The answers explain there what the IV is for and under what circumstances reuse is a problem and why and in which cases it is not a problem - i.e. when you only use a key once.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for linking the duplicate question! :)